# What is the best approach to build a react app with a large amount of component pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been tasked with building an application in ReactJS that will have roughly 70 - 100 pages / subpages. So far I've tried building this so each page is it's own component i.e. mainPage.js , subPage1.js, subPage2.js etc. but in the long run there will be far too many pages to maintain. Many of the pages follow the same structure like the code below, but each page will of course have it's own unique data.
    `<Header>`
    `<Main Content>`
    `<Footer>`

So my question is, is there a way to dynamically create pages in React or a way of creating component pages so that I don't have to create a seperate page for every single different page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use react [component composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). Sounds like you've already some header, content, footer components. You should categorize the types of pages your app uses and create general purpose container components for each use-case.

For example, a "base" or "first-level" page component *could* look like:

```
const Page = ({ pageHeaderProps, pageFooterProps, ...props }) => (
  <Page.Container>
    <Page.Header {...pageHeaderProps} />
    <Page.Content {...props} />
    <Page.Footer {...pageFooterProps} />
  </Page.Container>
);
```

Here the `children` prop is spread into the (or wrapped by) `Content` component.

If for example some sub-pages have an additional sub-header or some other common component, then you can compose a component as:

```
const SubPage = ({ children, subHeaderProps, ...props }) => (
  <Page {...props}>
    <SubHeader {...subHeaderProps} />
    {...children}
  </Page>
);
```

Here the new `SubHeader` is injected as a child of the `Page` and will be rendered as part of all the children it renders.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! This has helped me a lot. I just have one question regarding how properties are passed down. How do I create unique properties for each sub page? Say I have my Base page component which looks something like <container> <head ...props><body ...props><foot ...props></container> how do i then go into say Sub Page component and pass all of the properties down from the head, body and foot components? I understand this may be confusing  so I can provide Code if you need

Comment: @seanrs97 They are passed in the props, same as any other component. In the example I shared, a `Page` has all the header and footer components, taking props specific to each, and the `SubPage` is passing on all the extra props it doesn't need by spreading them into a variable named `props`, which is then spread back into the `Page` component to handle.